# How to pass through OUATH verification in C#

Tags: c#, email, oauth-2.0, outlook, mailkit

I'm trying to log into my `Outlook` mailbox via two-factor `authentication`. For this I use the `MailKit` library. I have implemented the example [https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/ExchangeOAuth2.md]
from the documentation into my example, but nothing is outputting. How is this possible? What am I doing wrong?
I am also confused about what represents in scopes `string` offline_access?

```
public async void OAUTH()
        {
            var options = new PublicClientApplicationOptions
            {
                ClientId = "ID",
                TenantId = "ID",
                RedirectUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient"
            };

            var publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .CreateWithApplicationOptions(options)
                .Build();

            var scopes = new string[] {
    "mailaddress",
    "offline_access", 
    "https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All", // Only needed for IMAP
    //"https://outlook.office.com/POP.AccessAsUser.All",  // Only needed for POP
    //"https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send", // Only needed for SMTP
};

            var authToken = await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

            var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(authToken.Account.Username, authToken.AccessToken);

            using (var client = new ImapClient())
            {
                
                using (var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource())
                {

                await client.ConnectAsync("outlook.office365.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
                await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);

                 //client.Authenticate(emailParser.Username, emailParser.Password, cancel.Token);


                    var inbox = client.Inbox;
                    inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly, cancel.Token);

                    Console.WriteLine("Total messages: {0}", inbox.Count);
                    Console.WriteLine("Recent messages: {0}", inbox.Unread);

                    for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var message = inbox.GetMessage(i, cancel.Token);
                        Console.WriteLine(message.TextBody);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: There could be a number of different issues.  Do you have more than one Outlook Office 365 account?  I've seen issues where one account works and another doesn't.  Office 365 can configure differently (port number, ssl, ...).  So sample may need to be modified.  Also if you are behind a company firewall you private outlook account will not work.  Inside a company firewall the email is port forwarded to the company email server and your email on an outside email server will not connect.  See if your code work on your home PC.

Comment: @jdweng I rather find it strange that it doesn't give me any output or throw an exception that I could use to bounce further

Comment: The connection is completing but you are not logging into the account. So the SMTP is getting a response and no exception is generated.  The status inside the response indicates a bad status.  The MailKit isn't reporting the bad status.  Did you check the client to see the status?

Comment: @jdweng Check client, you mean by `ProtocolLogger()`?

Comment: The client = new ImapClient()

Comment: @jdweng sorry, I don't understand what do you mean this by?